# Password protect CUPs server printer

Tags: cups

I have a CUPS server, and a computer lab of Ubuntu clients.

The clients read available printers directly from the server with

`/etc/cups/client.conf`  -->  `ServerName myCupsServer`

I currently have one printer that is restricted by username (via the cups web interface at `myCupsServer:631`).  This printer only appears for permitted users.

Is there a way to have this printer appear for all users, but require a password when printing to it?